# wordpress нет captcha в комментариях

Tags: wordpress, captcha

Есть проблема с капчей, перепробовал несколько разных плагинов, а поведение их одинаковое: капча есть везде кроме формы комментария.
Причём и в форме логина и в форме комментария есть код для отображения поля с капчей, однако в исходном коде внизу страницы скрипты для капчи есть только в форме логина, а на странице с формой комментария этих строк нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть.

Comment: Смотреть никуда невозможно, потому что в вопросе информации ноль. Какие конкретно плагины ставили - непонятно.

Comment: Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/) - стоит сейчас, Login No Captcha reCAPTCHA (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/login-recaptcha/), Simple Google reCAPTCHA (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-google-recaptcha/), Advanced noCaptcha reCaptcha (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-nocaptcha-recaptcha/)

Comment: Капчи - зло! Есть  100500 нормальных спобов обойтись без капчи. Начиная от акисмета и заканчивая скрытыми полями.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте плагин [Невидимая reCaptcha для WordPress](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/invisible-recaptcha/). Он не только подключает новейшую Invisible reCaptcha от Google, но и решает ваш вопрос с защитой формы комментариев:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставил, не помогло, мало того, на форме логина капча тоже перестала подгружаться.

Comment: Вы все другие плагины уберите. Этот плагин работает на 146%, я его использую на десятке сайтов.